# Infinite socket connect attempt in python

Tags: python, sockets

Is it possible for socket to keep attempting to connect to specified socket until the connection is established?

If it's possible do you mind showing me on example how it's done? I searched around google and on stack overflow but didn't find anything useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
while True:
   if do_connection_attempt():
       break
```

where `do_connection_attempt` is a placeholder for the connection attempting phase, returning `True` if connection was established?

Comment: Or, more tersely: `while not do_connection_attempt(): pass`

Comment: It should include a timeout or sleep to keep CPU usage resonable.

Comment: It can do this in `do_connection_attempt()`. It will improve readability if the loop is left this way (cdhowie's way)

Answer (score -2):

Have you meant something like this?

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        try:
            self.csock.connect(self.ADDR)
        except socket.error:
            self.run()
```

If so, this produces error after few attempts.

Comment: Somehow I don't think a recursive call inside of an infinite loop with no breaks is a very good idea...

Comment: It sure produce errors, as it is case of infinite recursion (if no connection is established)

Comment: How this should be written then? I'm completely lost now.

Comment: @ber This will cause an infinite recursion even if the connection was established as repeating attempt to connect on a connected socket is bound to cause an error, and there is no way out of this loop.